# Error in MANIFEST.MF of SWTBot test plugin

Tags: eclipse, swtbot

I would want to try out SWTBot to test our RCP application's user interface. For that I started with the sample test which worked perfectly as [documented here](http://swtbot.com/user-guide/running-swtbot-tests.html). I wanted to try similarly on our application and for that I checked out our UI plugin and was able to launch it as eclipse application. Then I created a new SWTBot test plugin. Just after creating test plugin, I see error "Bundle 'org.eclipse.swtbot.go' cannot be resolved" in MANIFEST.MF file on line "Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.swtbot.go".

I am not sure why I am getting this error only when I try to create the test plugin for our custom RCP application and not when I am trying out the example provided in the above link. I compared both test plugin MANIFEST.MF file but left with no clue.

Has anyone faced such error while creating the SWTBot test plugin for the custom RCP application?

Thanks in advance !!

Prakash

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `org.eclipse.swtbot.go` is actually the name of the plugin (maybe the plugin is called something else).

Make sure your target platform in PDE contains the SWTBot stuff. You can also use the PDE Plugins view to see if you see the SWTBot plugins.

Comment: Thanks a lot Francis!! It worked for me. I had set the target platform to my java plugin, which I was suppose to change to Running Platform.